# How to improve Docker build output when using `RUN` with a HEREDOC?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Given the Dockerfile:

```
FROM <some-image>
RUN <<`
  set -e
  # do multiple lines of commands
`
```

This is output during `docker buildx build` as:

> => [2/2] RUN <<` (set -e...)

It is not clear which `RUN` command this was, since any using this HEREDOC format will look the same. I'd like to be able to use this HEREDOC format, while also having the build output be more clear, e.g.:

```
RUN <<` echo Installing deps...
  set -e
  # do multiple lines of commands
`
```

Which gives the output:

> => [2/2] RUN <<` echo Installing deps...

So I can clearly see which `RUN` HEREDOC is being executed. But this does not work, and neither does:

```
RUN <<` # Installing deps...
  set -e
  # do multiple lines of commands
`
```

Because the multiline HEREDOC is strung together when it's executed, into a single line.

---

To solve this, I could just simply `ECHO` before my `RUN` directives which use HEREDOCs:

```
RUN echo Installing deps...
RUN <<`
  set -e
  # do multiple lines of commands
`

But is it the proper way, since it adds a useless `RUN` directive?
```